# How to get a list of Facebook ad accounts that an application has access to

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not sure if there is an end point to fulfill this request, couldn't find anything in their docs hence the question.

My app has access to a bunch of advertiser accounts and I would like to get a list of them with an API call. I've tried /me/accounts?fields=id,name in the Graph API Explorer but it doesn't list anything, neither does it throw any exception.

I have access to the accounts as I can make API calls and also get the UI through https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage?act=11111111111
Please let me know if more details are needed around this. Thanks.

Comment: When you say you couldn't find anything in the docs, did you look at the User object documentation? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user - If your app is in the Ads API whitelist, it's accessible at `/me/adaccounts`

Comment: I, in fact had looked at that documentation, but somehow after trying me/accounts I skipped the next connection object. Thank you, that was the object I was looking for. If you could please put that as a separate post, I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of a user's ad accounts is the [`/<USER>/adaccounts` connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/).

Your app needs [access to the Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access/) and have the `ads_management` permission to be able to access this data.

Comment: A follow up question, a few ad accounts do not have names defined and the API returns empty string. But on FB Manage Ads UI, I see their email addresses after the account id. eg. 123456(myfbadvt@advertiser.com,USD). Which field gives me that email id? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that field is returned from the API, it's the business user's email address that they use to log in, I think

Comment: @Igy firstly thank you for answering these questions, they have been very helpful to me. However, it would be nice if FB's documentation for this request were more accurate/readable. It is in no way clear what will be returned. In addition to that it's very unclear to me which requests I can and cannot make. Calling this other thing the "ads api" when it is really just part of the graph api is rather confusing, I am getting an insufficient permissions error but the boundary between the graph and ads api's is not clear to me so I'm not sure which requests I can and cannot make.

Comment: Anything which requires ads_management permission or Ads API access should be marked as such in the documentation (and anything under the Ads API section of the docs can be assumed to require ads api access) - if not, you can file a bug report against the docs and we'll make it clearer